# Can't Call For Image From Resources For New PictureBox

Tags: c#, picturebox

As soon as the block intersects the collision bar, I want it to stop moving & produce a new picture box with the same image and inherit its parent's code (Essentially a clone). For some reason, the new PictureBox (block) is not visible & I believe this is due to it not being able to inherit the image from the resource directory. Could someone please help?

```
 if (block.Bounds.IntersectsWith(colbar1.Bounds)) // Stacking Spot
        {
            fall2.Enabled = false;

            block = new PictureBox();
            block.Image = Properties.Resources.Block;
            block.SizeMode = PictureBoxSizeMode.AutoSize;

            block.Location = target.Location;
            fall.Enabled = true;
        }
```

Comment: Once you call `block = new PictureBox();`, you have to add it to the parent again, like `this.Controls.Add(block);`.  You would have to reattach any event handlers, too.